# How to say "all together" in Latin when inviting people to sing?

Tags: chant

I am the canter at my local Catholic Church, and need to discretely say "all together" in Latin to invite people to sing the response for the Kyrie, and other chants.

I've found a few words that might match the meaning I'm looking for, but I'm not very experienced with Latin grammatical rules, and don't want to say something that cannot be used by itself. I rather learn the translations of the chants by heart, and therefore only know the words I ever had to use when signing.

These two sources provide a few plausible expressions:

- https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the/latin-word-for-9034ff9e2b8f00b47a44dfaf3c2a37176c101e2a.html
- https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the/latin-word-for-d87c448044defb778f33158d8ccf94a20531d600.html

Or is there a commonly used expression that canters or the priest use to indicate to the assembly to sing along?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know what is usually said, but in musical notation, the expressions are sometimes found:

- Omnes ([example here](https://books.google.de/books?id=9Rfq4LulfmUC&pg=PA241&sa=X#v=onepage&q&f=f))
- Chorus plenus
- Concentus plenus

*Chorus/concentus plenus* means "the full chorus," which seems like it is not really a form of address. I would therefore suggest saying *Omnes*, which, to be honest, would have been a very obvious idea in the first place.

Comment: What about "canite una" = "(All) sing at the same time"/ "in one company"/ "together", where "una" is an adverb?

Comment: @tony Sounds valid and correct, but I would say I prefer _omnes_ for practical reasons, given that it is shorter and more discrete. Thanks, though!

Comment: I like *omnes*, or maybe *omnes una*, which is almost a calque of the English phrase.

Answer (score 2):

What about “toti”? The advantage is that in Italian (the Latin of classical music) you use “tutti” to mean “all together”, the opposite of “solo”.

Comment: Not bad.  Thank you. :)

Comment: I think this is the best answer. It would be immediately obvious to me, but perhaps that's from listening to classical music.